# How can I scale objects from the center in OpenGL ES 2.0 using matrices?

Tags: opengl-es, matrix

Right now in my vertex shader I multiply the position by a matrix that contains translation and scale:

```
gl_Position = ModelView * Position;
```

(`ModelView` is a `uniform mat4`)

And here is the structure of `ModelView`:

```
GLfloat matrix[16] = {
    sx, 0, 0, 0,
    0, sy, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1.0f, 0,
    tx, ty, 0, 1.0f
};
```

Where `sx` and `sy` are scale (default `1.0f`) and tx and ty and translations (default `0.0f`).

The translation works fine... But when I scale objects (change the scale from `1.0f` to anything else), their position changes (they aren't being scaled from the center?) I can translate objects back into their correct position using an algorithm, but is there something I can do with matrices to fix this (without having to edit the translation)?

I am working in a 2D environment hence why I don't have a `tz` or `sz`. I think I have to add a projection matrix? I couldn't find 2D examples or resources I could understand.

Comment: Why don't you rather do matrix operations such as scale or simply multiply these 2 matrices? All you probably need is to put tx*sx and ty*sy for the translation part of the matrix.

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work. Even if the object has no translation (tx and ty are 0) it is still in a very wrong position depending on the weight of the scale (the more it is scaled, the further it is from where it SHOULD be). I don't think it is a huge deal because I've figured out how to dynamically translate all scaled objects back to their correct positions. I just thought it was weird that I had to do this though.